# Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

While installing Android studio 2.1 version and it downloaded the required components and end of the detailed view logs it shows,

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installed successfully!
Creating Android virtual device
Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device
```

I'm running Android studio for the first time in Windows 7.

Screenshot:

[image: Android_Studio_setup_wizard_downloading_components_error]

And after opening the Andriod studio and running a sample app, I get the error

```
Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD
```

Why is it unable to create a virtual device and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I've run into this today. Running the studio.sh from a terminal I could see the actual error (disk full in my case). So this should be the first place to look at if you get this error. I also think that deleting everything (two .android* directories in the home directory and the Sdk one) and starting over is the best strategy to avoid problems later.

Comment: I needed also to remove `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I don't know what exactly caused the avd creation problem in a new laptop. I did exactly the same thing as user @Jamalla posted. I clicked finish and tried to run my sample app in the existing emulator. As Jamalla pointed out the `config.ini` file was corrupted. So I deleted the existing AVD and created a new one. But I couldn't start it either because my VT was not enabled in my BIOS.

After enabling my VTx in BIOS menu I was able to start the AVD with no issues.

Answer (score 6):

All what you can do with that screen is just to click finish.

The problem that you may get as a result is failing in creating a first Virtual Device for you because its config file is either missing (not created) or corrupted !
[image: config file is either missing (not created) or corrupted]

So what you would do is just to create your own new Virtual Device and delete the corrupted one!
[image: reate your own new Virtual Device]

Comment: Thanks @Jamalla I did the same thing already. However enabling vt in my bios solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem running emulator on OSX El Capatain. It turned out .android directory owner was root. I have changed the ownership resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, I installed some 32-bit libraries as stated in installation instructions on the Android Studio web page with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`

After the above command I reinstalled the Android Studio the problem disappeared.